# Twilio Whatsapp API Voice recognizing according to Jan 2020 update using NodeJs

Tags: node.js, twilio, chatbot, whatsapp

I'm developing a whatsapp chatbot using twilio, it works fine, only Voice Messages, can't be recognized, and whatsapp reply is: "I didn't get that. can you say that again?"
I know that Twilio Whatsapp API wasn't able handle voice messages, but few days ago, I received a message from twilio support that now they are able handle voice message, and they share with me that [**link**](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/whatsapp/tutorial/send-and-receive-media-messages-whatsapp-nodejs?code-sample=code-send-a-media-message-with-whatsapp&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x)

They said that

> Voice messages are possible now, they have to be sent as OGG audio
>   files though with the .opus extension.

I tried to make it work, but I can't,

How can I catch the voice message which user add to chatbot, and how to convert it to OGG audio with .opus extension, or is there any other method I can do to make the chatbot recognize user voice messagge?

Comment: Are you trying to send or receive audio files over whatsapp? Can you share the code you are using so we can look into it and debug?

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am stuck here too

Comment: I still contacting twilio customer support trying to apply the solution on my chatbot project because I can't make it work because I'm using dialogflow inline editor, but for those whom use external webhock, the [link](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/whatsapp/tutorial/send-and-receive-media-messages-whatsapp-nodejs?code-sample=code-send-a-media-message-with-whatsapp&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x) in the post may work for them  @MuhammadNaufil